# How to Hide post that have same category

Tags: wordpress

is there someone who knows how to hide post that have same category?

I have Post 1, Post 2, Post 3 that have same category. Can i just show the latest post ( post 1) at my homepage, and hide other post ( post 2 and post 3 )

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to have three separate wp_queries.

```
//Query 1
$args1 = array(
    'cat'                    => '1',
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
);    $query_1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
if ( $query_1->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_1->have_posts() ) {
        $query_1->the_post();
        // put content here
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata();

//Query 2
$args2 = array(
    'cat'                    => '2',
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
);    $query_2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if ( $query_2->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_2->have_posts() ) {
        $query_2->the_post();
        // put content here
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata();

//Query 3
$args3 = array(
    'cat'                    => '3',
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '1',
);    $query_3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
if ( $query_3->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_3->have_posts() ) {
        $query_3->the_post();
        // put content here
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'offset' => 0,
        'category' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );

    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <!-- pagination here -->

        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->

        <!-- pagination here -->

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Add your category ID to 'category'.
reefer these links for more information.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Answer (score 0):

> You can achieve this by alter the query of home page throught [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook.

Here is the code:

```
function txt_domain_get_distinct_post_id()
{
    $post_ids = [];

    //getting all non empty category 
    $categories = get_terms('category', array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
    ));

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'category' => $category->term_id,
            'exclude' => $post_ids,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
        //getting post from a specific category
        $postlist = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($postlist as $post)
        {
            if (!in_array($post->ID, $post_ids))
            {
                //this will only select one post form each category
                $post_ids[] = $post->ID;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $post_ids;
}


add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'txt_domain_filter_get_posts' );

function txt_domain_filter_get_posts($query)
{
    if (is_home() && $query->is_main_query())
    {
        $post_ids = txt_domain_get_distinct_post_id();
        $query->set('post__in', $post_ids);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

---

Reference:

- [is_home()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Main_Page)
- [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)
- [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)